# Webscraping options chain from Euronext for all expiry dates in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance

I'm trying to scrape the optionschain from Euronext. For example, for the company Heineken, the weburl is https://live.euronext.com/en/product/index-options/HEI-DAMS.

Currently, I am only able to get the options chain for the next expiry date.

What I used is the following:

```
import requests
url = 'https://live.euronext.com/en/ajax/getPricesOptionsAjax/stock-options/HEI/DAMS/' 
req = requests.get(url).json()
```

How do I generalize this such that I get the options for all expiry dates?

Edit: looking at the answer of D.L, who put in considerable effort to understand my question, I got the impression that I needed to provide extra information to clearify what I am looking for.

When you go the the URL provided above, you will find: [image]

The above code *by default* will indeed provide all the data that is available on the page. However, Selecting 'Select All', will show more data for other expiry dates on the webpage. It is those datapoints that are missing running the current script.

For example, the February 2024 options will not show up by default, but only after selecting 'Select all'. [image]

I'm hoping to adjust the code above in such a way that I also get the data for the other expiry dates.

EDIT2:
I can also see that the following is used in the form.

[image]

Hence, I tried:

```
import requests
url = 'https://live.euronext.com/en/ajax/getPricesOptionsAjax/stock-options/HEI/DAMS/'
form_data = {"md%5B%5D": "04-2024", "ps": "11"}
req = requests.post(url, data=form_data)
```

But this yields the same result. only the January data.

Thanks again.

Comment: i can see all of the data when i run this code.

Comment: the result is too large to post as an answer, but it is a structured json.

Comment: Are you sure? data = req['simple'] gives me the output starting with "[{'maturityDate': 'January 2024', 'volumeDate': '19/01/24', 'data': [". But no other maturity dates. So only 'maturityDate': 'January 2024'.

Comment: i literally get everything.  in fact, as i said above, the response is too large for me to post as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I can see all of the data. I use `pprint` to show the result structure.

here is the code i used:

```py
import pprint
import requests
url = 'https://live.euronext.com/en/ajax/getPricesOptionsAjax/stock-options/HEI/DAMS/' 
req = requests.get(url).json()

pprint.pp(req)
```

the result is a dict with 2 keys. you can see the keys by doing this:

```py
for k in req.keys():
    print(k)
```

which returns this:

```
extended
simple
```

The values are **large** lists (too long to show here, so i show the first half only).

```
'extended': [{'maturityDate': 'January 2024',
               'volumeDate': '19/01/24',
               'rowc': [{'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=860000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">86.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '5.60',
                         'volume': '2',
                         'last_date': '15:03',
                         'daily_vol': '5',
                         'open_interest': '279',
                         'settl': '5.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=870000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">87.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '-',
                         'settl': '4.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=880000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">88.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '3.61',
                         'volume': '4',
                         'last_date': '12:38',
                         'daily_vol': '5',
                         'open_interest': '2,064',
                         'settl': '3.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=890000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">89.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '2.43',
                         'volume': '1',
                         'last_date': '17:11',
                         'daily_vol': '1',
                         'open_interest': '3',
                         'settl': '2.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=900000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">90.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '1.40',
                         'volume': '5',
                         'last_date': '17:13',
                         'daily_vol': '17',
                         'open_interest': '383',
                         'settl': '1.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=910000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">91.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': True,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.42',
                         'volume': '4',
                         'last_date': '17:12',
                         'daily_vol': '12',
                         'open_interest': '185',
                         'settl': '0.46'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=920000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">92.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.01',
                         'volume': '1',
                         'last_date': '17:22',
                         'daily_vol': '10',
                         'open_interest': '394',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=930000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">93.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.03',
                         'volume': '10',
                         'last_date': '16:22',
                         'daily_vol': '11',
                         'open_interest': '54',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=940000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">94.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '326',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=950000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">95.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.01',
                         'volume': '10',
                         'last_date': '15:40',
                         'daily_vol': '10',
                         'open_interest': '24',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=C&amp;sp=960000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">96.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '86',
                         'settl': '0.01'}],
               'rowp': [{'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=860000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">86.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=870000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">87.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=880000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">88.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=890000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">89.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=900000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">90.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.03',
                         'volume': '1',
                         'last_date': '16:04',
                         'daily_vol': '4',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=910000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">91.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': True,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '0.01',
                         'settl': '0.01'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=920000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">92.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '0.60',
                         'volume': '1',
                         'last_date': '17:11',
                         'daily_vol': '27',
                         'open_interest': '0.54',
                         'settl': '0.54'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=930000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">93.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '1.76',
                         'volume': '1',
                         'last_date': '16:40',
                         'daily_vol': '11',
                         'open_interest': '1.54',
                         'settl': '1.54'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=940000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">94.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '2.54',
                         'settl': '2.54'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=950000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">95.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '3.54',
                         'settl': '3.54'},
                        {'strike': '<a '
                                   'href="/en/product/stock-options/HEI-DAMS/instrument?Class_symbol=HEI&amp;ps=pagesize&amp;pmd=maturitydates&amp;Class_exchange=DAMS&amp;fOrO=O&amp;cOrP=P&amp;sp=960000000&amp;md=01-2024" '
                                   'class="text-ui-picton-blue '
                                   'font-weight-bold">96.00</a>',
                         'atTheMoney': False,
                         'best_bid': '-',
                         'best_ask': '-',
                         'last': '-',
                         'volume': '-',
                         'last_date': '20:23',
                         'daily_vol': '-',
                         'open_interest': '4.54',
                         'settl': '4.54'}]}],
```

The lists have further structure.

So in summary, you need to know the exact structure for what you are seeking.

Comment: Hi D.L., thanks a lot for your help. Perhaps my question was not clear enough. I still only see options data for one maturity in your output, namely for January 2024. I also get the two values, simple and extended and the accompanying large lists. However, I would want to have the same two values and large lists for other maturities, so for example for Heineken, February and March data are also available on the website url, but I do not get that in my output (and I also do not see it in yours).

Comment: I have adjusted the opening question in a way that I hope is more clear. Thanks again.